# Can I use Sql Server Database from iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database

There are a lot of ways to have a database on server ( I can use my own server or I can use MS Azure (for Azure I found REST API Description https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/gg715283.aspx , but I didn't find a way to add some rows to a table or to get information from the table)), but I want to edit the database and get proper rows from the server database from iOS code without having server API. There are a lot of ready solutions such as Backendless.com , but they are not stable.

So is there any way to connect to the remote SQL server database on the remove server or to MS Azure database and to edit rows and fetch data?
May there are some framework for iOS to do than? (for example in .Net there are Linq framework and Entity Framework).

Comment: Is there any reason you don't want to use REST API? I think what you're looking for is possible but must be messy way.

Comment: I want to use REST API but I didn't find any methods of REST API to add a row to a table or to fetch data from database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your question, you linked to a *management API* for SQL Database service - this has nothing to do with data manipulation; it's strictly a management API for dealing with servers and databases.

If you want to direct-connect from an IOS app to SQL Database Service (or SQL Server in a VM), you'd need to find a client library for IOS (and recommendations of such a library are not in scope for StackOverflow). There is no native SQL Server client library specifically provided through the Azure SDKs / APIs.

Outside of a native client library, there is Azure Mobile Services, which provides an API stack specifically designed around use by mobile apps (whether IOS, Android, Windows Phone, or even JavaScript). The API stack provided here, by default, gives CRUD operations for SQL Database tables. Additionally, it supports adding custom API calls, where you have complete control of your API calls.

Any other API stack would require you to choose the stack and run it yourself (whether in a Linux or Windows VM, Cloud Service, or Web App - there's no single right way to do this).

Documentation for Azure Mobile Apps (and related API feature, such as monitoring) is [here](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/services/app-service/mobile/).

Answer (score 0):

Since you are developing in Azure consider automatic REST API from SlashDB, which is available from their Marketplace.

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/marketplace/partners/vte/slashdb-slashdb-azure/

SlashDB reflects the entire database as URL-linked structure so a lot of queries need not even be written. It supports SELECT, INSERT and UPDATE. In addition to that it allows for defining an API end-point to call a stored procedure or return results of a SQL query.

Disclosure: I am the founder and CEO of the company behind SlashDB, but you don't have to take my word it - just try it.

Comment: The fact you disclosed your affiliation with SlashDB is commendable (since this tends to be the exception). That said: This isn't the place to promote a product framework.